# Which .config file is used for a test dll?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, .net-assembly, assembly-resolution

In my output folder, there is two .config files :

- app.config
- app.UnitTest.config

i am wondering which one is used at runtime for test dll, the obvious answer will be app.UnitTest.config, but, is there any cases where app.config is used ?

N.B.
I am using NUnit.

Comment: I presume you also have app.dll and app.UnitTest.dll

Comment: @phuzi yes exactly

Comment: app.dll will use app.config and app.UnitTest.dll will use app.UnitTest.config. So when running unit tests (presumably in your app.UnitTest project) you the app.UnitTest.config will be used instead of app.config.